# How to connect to Oracle with datamapper jdbc adapter (in JRuby) and check connection?

Tags: oracle, jdbc, jruby, datamapper

How to connect to Oracle with datamapper jdbc adapter (in JRuby) and check connection? I can't understand the documentation :D

If you have some example - give me please

Comment: I don't now how to write the code :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

require 'data_mapper'

require 'dm-oracle-adapter'

adapter = DataMapper.setup(:default, 'oracle://user:password@host/ORCL')

z = adapter.select('select 1 from dual')